# Form's submit actions not working after disabling SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE cookie

Tags: xconnect, cookies

I implemented code to block the `SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE` cookie if the consent has not been given (based on [this blog post](https://www.3chillies.co.uk/blog/2021/07/sitecore-global-analytics-cookie-and-cookie-consent)). But after doing that, I noticed, that none of the form's submit actions work (at first I noticed the "**Show Page Form**" from `Sitecore Form Extensions` did not work, but tried with "**Send Email**", and it did not work anymore as well). It is mentioned in the blog post, that disabling that cookie will disable any features that use XConnect, although I am not sure if Submit Actions are part of XConnect. It feels like aborting the "**startAnalytics**" pipeline is blocking the submit actions, but I am not sure if that's how it's supposed to be working or could be there another issue.

I did not see anything in the logs. Working on `Sitecore 10.1.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw exactly the same issue when analytics cookie was blocked but form still was configured to use Robots Detection.

There were 2 options to fix the issue:

- disable globally Robots detection with setting:

```xml
 <setting name="Analytics.AutoDetectBots" value="false"/>
```

- disable robots detection on forms themselves:

  [image: sitecore forms disable robots detection]